# Why is the chording angle 30 degrees, in a practical alternator?

Tags: synchronous, electrical, harmonics, alternator

So far what i have understood...

Chording angle in Synchronous Generator/ Alternator is introduced to tackle the problem of harmonics that couldn't be taken care of during the design either in -

- Salient Pole Rotor: As the **POLE PITCH/POLE ARC percentage is ~70%**
- Cylindrical Pole Rotor : As we can't achieve a stepped sinusoidal mmf in the air gap, given that the **manufacturers are reluctant to cut the slots with different dye's as they are costly**. Even if this were to be done then slot harmonics will still enter the air gap.

***So basically harmonics in the air gap of an alternator are going to be there, no matter what, can't be avoided...***

To deal with this chording factor was introduced.

Kc  = cos(a/2)   --> For Fundamental

Kcn = cos(n*a/2) --> For Nth Harmonic

*My question is :*

In practical data of alternators most of the time the chording angle is kept 30 degrees, to reduce the belt harmonics component i.e 5th and 7th, but wouldn't 3rd harmonic have more effect on the fundamental than the 5th and 7th, why did we not keep the chording angle to 60 degrees, which would had eliminated the 3rd harmonics, something that we usually do?

Comment: I believe that the nature of the machine construction leads to a symmetry of the generated waveform such that no harmonics divisible by 3 are present. I don't have the time to verify that or find a detailed explanation.

Comment: @CharlesCowie, thanks for the reply, but i am very much interested in the proof of the same which i wasn't able to find in any good machines book, revert back to this question whenever you have time.. thanks once again.

Comment: I believe that my previous comment is circular reasoning. The symmetry that I recall is the symmetry of the pattern of stepped mmd in the air gap. That is achieved by the pattern of distributed windings. I think that is the same thing as the chording factor.

Comment: I neglected the most basic factor. No triplen harmonic current can flow in a wye connected machine assuming that loads are not connected to the neutral. Triplens can also be eliminated by connecting to the transmission line through a D-Y or Y-D transformer.

Comment: I had approached my professor for the same, and even he concurs with your third point. If you could just post that as an answer, so that i could accept it. Thanks @CharlesCowie. This was boggling me for quite some time now...